# What is the bash syntax for extracting the values from multiple instances of the same argument?

Tags: bash, command-line, parameter

I want to use multiple instances of command line paramater such as the `-d` option used by `PHP` for passing `PHP` options. I am currently using the `getopts` command in `bash`.

With PHP invocation it would look like this:

```
php -f aPHPscript.php -d memory_limit=120M -d apc=1 -d max_execution_time=120
```

How would the multiple instances of the parameter be extracted in a bash script? Is there a bash command for doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash doesn't typically care about the values of the arguments, it's more their ordering, and how they're separated on the command line, by default parsing them based on a space between each argument.

You can see this with a simple `for` loop construct in a shell script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ""
echo "ARGS: $@"

echo ""
echo "parsed args:"
for i in "$@"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

#### Example

```
$ ./parse.bash -f aPHPscript.php -d memory_limit=120M -d apc=1 \
     -d max_execution_time=120

ARGS: -f aPHPscript.php -d memory_limit=120M -d apc=1 -d max_execution_time=120

parsed args:
-f
aPHPscript.php
-d
memory_limit=120M
-d
apc=1
-d
max_execution_time=120
```

In the above, each iteration through the loop is "peeling off" the next argument that was passed into the script `parse.bash`. So rather then use `getopts` you could always do something like this.

#### Using while + case

I typically don't use `getopts` and do things as you're inquiring about like so with a `while` loop using a `case` statement to parse the arguments as required.

```
$ more parse2.bash 
#!/bin/bash

while [[ $# > 1 ]]
do
key="$1"
shift

#  -f aPHPscript.php -d memory_limit=120M -d apc=1 
#+ -d max_execution_time=120

case $key in
    -f)
    f_ARG="$1"
    shift
    ;;
    -d)
    d_ARGS=( "${d_ARGS[@]}" "$1" )
    shift
    ;;
    *)
            # unknown option
    ;;
esac
done

echo "$f_ARG"
echo "${d_ARGS[@]}"
```

When we run it with your arguments we can see that it was able to parse your `-d` arguments into an array, `$d_ARGS`.

```
$ ./parse2.bash -f aPHPscript.php -d memory_limit=120M -d apc=1 \
      -d max_execution_time=120
aPHPscript.php
memory_limit=120M apc=1 max_execution_time=120
```

#### References

- [How do I parse command line arguments in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash)
- [Chapter 27. Arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html)

Comment: Why recommend against the use of `getopts`? It's there. It works. It does option bundling.

Comment: @Gilles - I wasn't saying not to use it, just that I generally don't.

Comment: I want to use a function to extract the parameters I need and reinsert them back into the original script where those parameters are required.

However it seems to me that `$#` variable is some kind of global that is permanently changed by `shift` command and manipulating it will affect the original script. Can it be copied to a separate variable to extract the required arguments?

Comment: @vfclists - when you shift you're popping the variables off of an array (`$@`). `$# reflects the index of the last element of that array.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `getopts` several times. You must take care what to do with the option arguments. You may use an index, write all arguments to `-d` to `option_d[index_d++]` so that you get an array. But that has nothing to do with `getopts`.